# PubNub push notifications won't display

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I've got this code set up in my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
PNConfiguration *pnConfiguration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:publishKey
                                                                   subscribeKey:subscribeKey];
self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:pnConfiguration];

/* push notifications */
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

As well as these two methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

    [self.client addPushNotificationsOnChannels:@[@"apns"] withDevicePushToken:deviceToken andCompletion:^(PNAcknowledgmentStatus *status) {

    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%s with error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}
```

I've added the entitlement to my app ID, and uploaded the certificate to the PubNub console as described [here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4)

Here's my code for sending a push notification:

```
[self.client publish:nil toChannel:@"apns" mobilePushPayload: @{@"aps": @{@"alert":message}}
withCompletion:^(PNPublishStatus *status) {
    // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
    // if (status.isError) // Handle modification error.
    // Check 'category' property to find out possible issue because
    // of which request did fail. Request can be resent using: [status retry];
}];
```

However, no notification is displayed on my iPhone when publishing from the iOS simulator. **Any idea why this is?**

Comment: Can you follow the [PubNub mobile push troubleshooting guide here](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues) and provide valuable data points from that if you still are unable to determine the issue?

Comment: Did the troubleshooting guide help?

Comment: @CraigConover still looking at it. Might be using Firebase as it looks like they also feature push notifications. Not sure what to go for yet

Comment: They do provide push notifications as does many other vendors but PubNub and Firebase are different on the realtime data streaming side.

Answer (score 0):

Push Notifications don't work on simulator. You will need to test on a real device.

Comment: I'm listening for the notification on my real iPhone 5S, but sending it from a simulator.